# Data for spare parts for large machines/equipments

Tags: data-request

#### Data request

I am looking for a data-set that contains information about the sales of spare parts after the original machine/equipment has been sold for a B2B environment. The data ideally should contain following information. I have taken example of car.

1. Part Type/Name (Spark Plug, side mirror)
2. Part quantity (2 side mirrors or 1 gear box)
3. Price and cost of the parts if available
4. Information about original product (product type, model, product cost etc.)
5. Severity level  (Clutch wire could have a high severity level, horn may have medium severity etc.)
6. Labor amount associated to fit the part
7. Whether part is covered in insurance/warranty etc.
8. Dealer information (number of product repaired daily or anything else etc.)
9. Margins of dealer on the spare part
10. More information (please read the context)

#### Context

I am trying to analyze the optimal pricing for spare parts for a B2B context. To see if manufacturer can increase prices to improve revenues/profit.

#### Region

Any Region of the world is fine.

#### License

Just for my own analysis purpose, I will not use it anywhere. So any license which allows me to analyze the data freely is sufficient. My objective is to familiarize myself with such kind of data and analysis.

#### Format

Most preferable would be a CSV or multiple .CSV along with information on the keys. Basically anything that can be easily read in R will work

#### Requirements

Data should be at transaction level, basically, one observation for each transaction.